# What is yarn equivalent of `npm show @types/react@* version`

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Does yarn have something that does the same as below?

```
λ npm show @types/react@* version
@types/react@0.14.27 '0.14.27'
@types/react@0.14.28 '0.14.28'
@types/react@0.14.29 '0.14.29'
@types/react@0.14.30 '0.14.30'
@types/react@0.14.31 '0.14.31'
@types/react@0.14.32 '0.14.32'
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yarn info @types/react versions
```

Answer (score 0):

For Yarn 2 you can do:

```
yarn npm info @types/react
```

Which shows all versions and a bunch of other stuff.